# How to insert radio button value into the database?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, radio-button

I want to insert selected radio button value into the database. just "yes" or "no". if anyone can give me an idea it would be a great help. I am using codeigniter framework. Thanks in advance.

**Model**

```
function add_reservation($reservation_model) {
        return $this->db->insert('reservations', $reservation_model);
    }
```

**Controller**

```
function add_reservation() {
        $reservation_model = new Reservation_model();
        $reservation_service = new Reservation_service();

        $reservation_model->set_date_cal(trim($this->input->post('date', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_date(strtotime($this->input->post('date', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_title(trim($this->input->post('selected_hall', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_type(trim($this->input->post('selected_time', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_description(trim($this->input->post('name', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_advanced_payment_status(trim($this->input->post('advanned_paid_radio_button', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_paid_amount(trim($this->input->post('paid_amount', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_fax(trim($this->input->post('fax', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_telephone_number(trim($this->input->post('telephone', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_address(trim($this->input->post('address', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_menu_no(trim($this->input->post('selected_menu_number', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_menu_price_per_plate(trim($this->input->post('menu_price', TRUE)));
        $reservation_model->set_is_deleted('0');

        $this->db->last_query();

        echo $reservation_service->add_reservation($reservation_model);
    }
```

**View**

```
<label for="advanced_paid">Advanced paid</label>                        
                        <div id="advanned_paid_radio_button">                           
                            <input type="radio" onclick="myFunction()" name="optionsRadios" id="yes" value="yes"> Yes
                            <input type="radio" onclick="myNoFunction()" name="optionsRadios" id="no" value="no"> No

                        </div>
```

In the javascript i have this.

```
                 function myFunction() {                               

                       if ($('input[id="yes').is(':checked')) {
                            $('div[id="paid"]').show();
                        }
                        if ($('input[id="no"]').is(':checked')) {
                            $('div[id="paid"]').hide();
                        }

                    }

                    function myNoFunction() {
                        if ($('input[id="no"]').is(':checked')) {
                            $('div[id="paid"]').hide();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What is the problem you facing now ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen When i insert data into the database radio button value is not going.i want to send the clicked radio button value. just as "yes" or "no"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is ,you are posting the `id` of radio button `advanned_paid_radio_button` which is wrong , you need to post the `name='optionsRadios'` of radio not `id` `advanned_paid_radio_button` in `controller`.

```
$reservation_model->set_advanced_payment_status(trim($this->input->post('optionsRadios', TRUE)));
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine the value of the radio button then you shall get it by `.val()`

And store it in a variable

```
if ($('input[id="yes').is(':checked')) {
$('div[id="paid"]').show();
var value = $(this).val();
//your ajax call shall be here
}

if ($('input[id="no"]').is(':checked')) {
$('div[id="paid"]').hide();
var value = $(this).val();
//your ajax call shall be here 
}
```

Then to update it in the database, You shall have a jquery-ajax call to the controller and insert/update the value in your database.

**Note :** If you just want to update it the `Yes` or `No` in the Database you don't even need to have functions `myFunction` or `myNoFunction`.

You can just have it in it's on change event

Comment: I used myFunction and myNoFunction for another purpose. i wanted to show a text field if the radio button is yes and hide it if it is no.for that purpose only i used those methods.

Comment: Now i want to send just yes or no value into anthor field

Comment: Okay, Then you are getting the result by `var value = $(this).val();` If the radio is clicked the `value`  will be `1` else `0`

Comment: You want to display `Yes` or `No` instead of `0` or `1` in some other place ?

Comment: Yes. I am using it for a search purpose later. anyway i will try as the way you said. Thank you.